# Android List View duplicate values on scroll in Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I am binding data to a List View control in Android. The data is stored in an ArrayList. In the getView() function of the Adapter, I get the entire list consisting of 23 items. In case the 'selectedval' is '1', I set values to the TextView in the Row.

However , despite the List consisting of 23 unique values I see duplicate values in the View. On debugging, I see that the values get duplicated on scroll.

Here is the code for the getView() function.

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View mView = convertView;

    if (mView == null){
        mView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_rate_card, null);
        FancyTextview mTxtName = (FancyTextview)mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_name);
        FancyTextview mTxtPrice = (FancyTextview)mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_price);

        if(selectedVal == 0){
            String laundryPrice = mRateCardData.get(position).getLaundryPrice();
            if(Integer.parseInt(laundryPrice) != 0 && laundryPrice != null)
            {   
                mTxtName.setText(mRateCardData.get(position).getName());
                mTxtPrice.setText(laundryPrice);
            }
        }
        if(selectedVal == 1){
            String IPrice = mRateCardData.get(position).getIroningPrice();
            String Iname = mRateCardData.get(position).getName();
            if(Integer.parseInt(IPrice) != 0 && IPrice != null)
            {
                mTxtPrice.setText(IPrice);
                mTxtName.setText(Iname);
            }
        }
        return mView;
    }
    else{
        return mView;
    }
}
```

I searched for this and think its got to do with the recycling of the view. But I have been unable to solve it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please, understand [how listview works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) ... then it should be obvious

Comment: @Selvin, I'm going through one of those times where simple things don't make sense. Just was looking out for help. Sorry if I am wasting time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are creating the view is incorrect.  You need to inflate a new view, only if the convertView comes in null, but you do need to set the data every time the getView is called.

I would suggest looking into using the [Holder](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) pattern:

You code should look something like this:

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View mView = convertView;

    if (mView == null){
        mView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_rate_card, null);
        FancyTextview mTxtName = (FancyTextview)mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_name);
        FancyTextview mTxtPrice = (FancyTextview)mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_price);

     }
     if(selectedVal == 0){
        String laundryPrice = mRateCardData.get(position).getLaundryPrice();
        if(Integer.parseInt(laundryPrice) != 0 && laundryPrice != null)
        {   
            mTxtName.setText(mRateCardData.get(position).getName());
            mTxtPrice.setText(laundryPrice);
        }
    } else if (selectedVal == 1) {
        String IPrice = mRateCardData.get(position).getIroningPrice();
        String Iname = mRateCardData.get(position).getName();
        if(Integer.parseInt(IPrice) != 0 && IPrice != null)
        {
            mTxtPrice.setText(IPrice);
            mTxtName.setText(Iname);
        }
   }



   return mView;

}
```

Comment: There's a reason this question was downvoted by people. The OP hasn't even performed a base level search which would have yeiled the answer to the listview's usage

Comment: OP has code that compiles and runs and has obviously been debugging it.  I see effort.  He just needs some guidance.

Comment: @humblerookie, thank you for being so understanding and considering the innumerable circumstances which may cause a Developer to ask such a 'silly' question without doing a basic search.

Comment: Thank you @GaryBak. I have not worked a lot on ListView. I am a part of StackOverflow beacuse of selfless developers like you who are ready to help.